# No Vibrate During Calls

Tags: notifications, calls

Is there a way to get my phone to not vibrate during calls? I want it to vibrate for various notifications when I'm not in a call, but it's a bit startling with my phone up to my ear.

I've found a few SMS apps that can do it, but I'm hoping for something general, across all notifications.

EDIT: Upon further testing, it seems that my phone (Moto G, Andriod version 5.1) doesn't vibrate during a call by default, but sometimes it messes up and allows the notification vibrate to go through.

Comment: https://androidforums.com/threads/help-turn-off-notification-vibrate-during-phone-calls.126748/

Answer (score 0):

It might be different on other devices, but in a Samsung this is how you do it:

In the dialer app go to menu>settings>call settings>call alerts>notify during calls. Turn that off.

Comment: I don't have that option on my Moto G. Also, does that just affect call notifications, or all notifications?

Comment: It mutes all notifications from vibrating during calls. Look in settings>sound>also vibrate during calls. See if you have such a setting

Comment: I have an option called "Also vibrate for calls", but that just toggles whether to vibrate as well as give the ringtone when receiving a call. Turns out that my phone doesn't allow notifications to vibrate during a call by default, but messes up sometimes (see the edit that I added to the OP). Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have that option "Notify during calls", but it additionally says "Hear a sound when receiving a new notification" – so it's not related to vibrate, it's also not changing anything for my hangout calls etc.